# how to restore data by mongodb journal file?

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I open the journal file "WiredTigerLog.0000000003" by "Sublime",but the content is garbled.

Luckily, I can identify the data I deleted from the garbled content！

[image: this is the content of WiredTigerLog]

I have searched for an afternoon, but still do not know how to recover data from the Journal file. Very much looking forward to your answer！

Comment: Anyone can help me?!Please!

Comment: Have you tried using tools such as bsondump, to see if they can make anything of it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything except start up your mongod server again:

> With journaling enabled, if mongod stops unexpectedly, the program can recover everything written to the journal. MongoDB will re-apply the write operations on restart and maintain a consistent state.

See [Manage Journaling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-journaling/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks.But the content of the journal is the remove operation，So,i don't think it is a good idea